# Deleting files older than 7 days based on part of filename as date over HTTP

Tags: bash, curl, ansible

I have a list of remote files. I can access these files using `curl` or `Ansible`. The list looks like this:

```
sqldbd_12_30_2020_14_29_30.tar.gz
sqldbd_12_30_2020_14_52_32.tar.gz
sqldbd_12_31_2020_14_57_49.tar.gz
sqldbp_12_31_2020_16_00_40.tar.gz
sqldbd_01_01_2021_16_29_57.tar.gz
sqldbd_01_02_2021_18_00_35.tar.gz
sqldbd_01_03_2021_20_00_33.tar.gz
sqldbd_01_03_2021_22_00_37.tar.gz
sqldbf_01_04_2021_00_00_37.tar.gz
sqldbc_01_06_2021_02_00_33.tar.gz
```

The date format is: `%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S` (custom date format). I would like to execute `curl DELETE` only against files older than 7 days. At the moment I managed to write:

```
#!/bin/bash

auth_token=$1
storage_url=$2
compare_date=$(date -d '-7 days' '+%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')

for line in $(cat backup_list.txt); do

  timestamp=$(echo "${line%.*.*}" | cut -d '_' -f 2,3,4,5,6,7)

  if [[ "$timestamp" < "$compare_date" ]]; then
    curl -k -X DELETE "${storage_url}/sql_backups/$line" -H "X-Auth-Token: ${auth_token}"
  fi
done
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work as expected and eventually all the files are getting deleted. I guess I could force the backup script to create the date string in a different format.

Comment: why don't you delete the files based on creation date, not based on file name

Comment: I am only allowed to use curl or Ansible uri to access the files.

Comment: the comparisation will work if you convert vars into yyyymmddhhmmss or into posix timestamps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-epoch-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

the comparisation will work if you convert vars into yyyymmddhhmmss or into posix timestamps

```
#!/bin/bash

auth_token=$1
storage_url=$2
# posix epoch
compare_date=$(date -d '-7 days' +'%s')

for line in $(cat backup_list.txt); do

  timestamp=$(echo "${line%.*.*}" | cut -d '_' -f 2,3,4,5,6,7)

  # YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss
  datetime="${timestamp:6:4}${timestamp:0:2}${timestamp:3:2} ${timestamp:11:2}:${timestamp:14:2}:${timestamp:17:2}"
  # posix epoch
  timestamp=$(date -u -d "$datetime" +'%s')

  if [[ "$timestamp" < "$compare_date" ]]; then
    curl -k -X DELETE "${storage_url}/sql_backups/$line" -H "X-Auth-Token: ${auth_token}"
  fi
done
```